# JS Multiple Long Keydown Action

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I'm trying to create game like Haxball. It will have 2 players that will play on the same computer and same keyboard.(One of them W-A-S-D, other with arrows) But there is a problem about the multiple key press actions. As you know, each of them will press at least one key for a long time and this means at least 2 keys will be pressed for a long time. How can i do that? I haven't found any solution for this. Are there anyone who solved this before ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Game` object, you can listen to the keydown and keyup events in one place, and then pass the events down to `Player` objects. Each `Player` object gets its own keymap which it uses to translate the event key codes into actions. You initialize each of the different player objects with a different keymap so that they won't collide.

The `Game` class:

```
class Game {
    constructor () {
        var handleKeyDown = this._handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        var handleKeyUp = this._handleKeyUp.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
        this._keyMaps = [
            {"87": "up", "65": "left", "73": "down", "67": "right"}
            {"38": "up", "37": "left", "40": "down", "39": "right"}
        ];
        this._players = [
            new Player(this._keyMaps[0]),
            new Player(this._keyMaps[1])
        ];
    }
    _handleKeyDown (event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this._players.length; i++) {
            this._players[i].handleKeyDown(event);
        }
    }
    _handleKeyUp (event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this._players.length; i++) {
            this._players[i].handleKeyUp(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the Player object:

```
class Player {
    constructor (keyMap) {
        this._keyMap = keyMap;
    }
    handleKeyDown (event) {
        // check to see if the event's keycode matches one of your keys
        // and take an action
        switch (this._keyMap[event.keyCode]) {
            case "up":
                // do something
                break;
            // etc.
            default:
                // do nothing
                break;
        }

    }
    handleKeyUp (event) {
        // check to see if the event's keycode matches one of your keys
        // and take an action
        // and take an action
        switch (this._keyMap[event.keyCode]) {
            case "up":
                // do something
                break;
            // etc.
            default:
                // do nothing
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code to initialize the whole thing:

```
var game = new Game();
```

(NOTE: The above uses ES6 classes. If you need to support older browsers, including IE, you will either need to rewrite using `function` or use a transpiler.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this solution is suitable for what you want or not. Make two functions for both keydown and keyup events.

```
<body onkeydown="KeyDownfunction(event)" onkeyup="KeyUPfunction(event)">
```

then declare variable for each key will use and put an initial value if not pressed and then change this value if you press it.

```
var moveL=false;
    var moveR=false;
    var moveU=false;
    var moveD=false;

function KeyDownfunction(e){
         if(e.keyCode==39 ){moveL=true};
         if(e.keyCode==37 ){moveR=true};
         if(e.keyCode==38 ){moveU=true};
         if(e.keyCode==40 ){moveD=true};

    }
     function KeyUPfunction(event){

         if(e.keyCode==39 ){moveL=false};
         if(e.keyCode==37 ){moveR=false};
         if(e.keyCode==38 ){moveU=false};
         if(e.keyCode==40 ){moveD=false};
        }
```

Then make a function that depends on the variables created and call it by setTimeOut so that more of the key work together simultaneously.

```
setTimeout("myfunction()",100)
function myfunction()
        {   if(moveL==true){/*place here  what you want to execute when  the key that 
           this variable represents is pressed */ } else {/*place here  what you want 
           to execute when  the key that this variable represents is  not pressed */}
            if(moveR==true){} else {};
            if(moveU==true){};else {};
            if(moveD==true){};else {};
        }
```

I hope this is what you're looking for. Let me know if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, it is worked for me. Actually this is an algorithm what i am looking for.